# How can I play an audio bookmarklet on click?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have tried to make it so when clicked play audio but this code doesn't work. I would also like to know how to implement this code that works.

```
javascript:(function(){ var style = document.createElement(%27style%27), styleContent = document.createTextNode(%27* { cursor: url(data:image/x-icon;base64,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javascript:(function(){ var style = document.createElement(%27style%27), styleContent = document.createTextNode(%27* { cursor: url() 22 22, auto !important}%27); style.appendChild(styleContent ); var caput = document.getElementsByTagName(%27head%27); caput[0].appendChild(style); })();) 22 22, auto !important}%27); style.appendChild(styleContent ); var caput = document.getElementsByTagName(%27head%27); caput[0].appendChild(style); })();
```

```
javascript:object.onclick = function(){var audio = new Audio('https://media1.vocaroo.com/mp3/12OdDSvf3CkE');  audio.play();};
```

This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to add an event listener for the `canplay` or `canplaythrough` event before calling `audio.play()`. Try this:

```js
javascript: (function() {  var audio = new Audio('https://media1.vocaroo.com/mp3/12OdDSvf3CkE');  audio.addEventListener('canplay', () =>{  audio.play();  });})();
```

A bit more readable:

```js
(function() {
    var audio = new Audio('https://media1.vocaroo.com/mp3/12OdDSvf3CkE');
    audio.addEventListener('canplay', () =>{
        audio.play();
    });
})();
```

Edit: P.S. Nice choice of audio clip :)